# Can someone help me with fixing the console so that it can add the homophone next to the name and number when it prints out?

Tags: java

Here is my code so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;

public class MostHomophones 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File f = new File("src/project2-input.txt.");
        Map<String, List<String>> hmap = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
        Map<String, Integer> hmap1 = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        int count = 0;
        String BufferLine, key, value;
        List<String> valueList = null;
        while ((BufferLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if ((BufferLine.charAt(0) != ';') && (BufferLine.charAt(1) != ';')) 
            {
                String[] splited = BufferLine.split("\\s+", 2);
                value = splited[0];
                key = splited[1];
                if (hmap.containsKey(key)) 
                {
                    valueList = hmap.get(key);
                    valueList.add(value);
                    Collections.sort(valueList);
                    hmap1.put(key, valueList.size());
                } 
                else 
                {
                    valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    valueList.add(value);
                    hmap.put(key, valueList);
                    hmap1.put(key, 1);

                }
            }
        }

        TreeMap<Integer, String> resultmap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        List<String> resultlist = null;
        for (Map.Entry entry : hmap1.entrySet()) 
        {
            String resultvalue = (String) entry.getKey();
            int resultkey = (int) entry.getValue();
            if (!resultmap.containsKey(resultkey)) 
            {
                resultmap.put(resultkey, resultvalue);
            }
        }

        int k;
        int highestRank = resultmap.lastKey();
        System.out.println("enter 1000");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = in.nextInt();
        int rankcount = 0;
        int totalcount = 0;
        int temp1 = input;
        while (totalcount <= input) 
        {
            int rank = highestRank - rankcount;
            System.out.println(rank);
            String temp = resultmap.get(rank); 
            if(rank == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            List<String> result = hmap.get(temp);

            int Listsize = result.size();
            temp1 = temp1 - Listsize;
            if (!(temp1 <= 0)) {// get all elments of that list
                totalcount = totalcount + Listsize;
                for (int i = 0; i < Listsize; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.println(result.get(i) + "\t" + rank);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                totalcount = totalcount + temp1;
                // get upto temp elemnts
                for (int i = 0; i < temp1; i++) 
                {
                    System.out.println(result.get(i) + "\t" + rank);
                }
            }
            rankcount++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I got.

```
enter 1000
1000
K EH1 R IY0 13
CAREY   K EH1 R IY0 13
CARIE   K EH1 R IY0 13
CARREY  K EH1 R IY0 13
CARRIE  K EH1 R IY0 13
CARRY(1)    K EH1 R IY0 13
CARY    K EH1 R IY0 13
KAIREY  K EH1 R IY0 13
...
ABRUZZESE   AA0 B R UW0 T S EY1 Z IY0 2
1
ABBATIELLO  AA0 B AA0 T IY0 EH1 L OW0 1
0
```

What I want the output to be like is this.

```
enter 1000
1000
13
CAREY   13
CARIE   13
CARREY  13
CARRIE  13
CARRY(1)    13
CARY    13
KAIREY  13
...
ABRUZZESE   2
1
ABBATIELLO  1
0
```

I added the if(rank = 0) loop with the break to avoid getting these errors

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at MostHomophones.main(MostHomophones.java:91)
```

I know that the System.out.print in the if else loops are the ones that print out the words and number of times the homophone is used but is there a way for me to fix this?